# Как с помощью notepad++ найти слово с определёнными буквами

Tags: notepad++

Есть файл в котором в каждой строке 8 букв латинского алфавита. Допустим известно только 6 букв неизвестен порядок. Как найти все подходящие наборы букв(строки).
Например известно bbbaad. Текст файла

```
aabbsdee (Не должно найти)
aabbbdde (Должно найти)
abbeeeee (Не должно найти)
bbbdaaee (Должно найти)
```

Спасибо всем кто попытается помочь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Нажмите ctrl-F.
2. Search Mode - regular expression
3. В строку поиска необходимо ввести следующую комбинацию:

```
^(?=(?:[^b\n]*b){3})(?=(?:[^a\n]*a){2})(?=(?:[^d\n]*d){1}).+$
```

Ее можно модифицировать при необходимости, для этого достаточно добавить еще одну такую "скобку" `(?=(?:[^your_symbol\n]*your_symbol){count_of_symbols})`

*P.S можно использовать не только латинские символы